# Can't make a segue in Side Menu

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm using [this](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu#preview-samples) Side Menu pod and I can't make a segue from this menu. On my Storyboard I have (initial) ViewController (MainViewController), NavigationController with RootController and again ViewController (GameController):

[image: Storyboard]

I created Segue from RootController to GameController and install Identifier: "ShowGame", then wrote some code for segue:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            break
        case 1:
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowGame", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        case 2:
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowGame", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

And nothing happen:

[image: Example]

I can't understand why it does not work, for previous projects (without side menu) this way was perfect, but now I have troubles. Please help.

**Details:**

[image: details]

**RootController code:**

```
import UIKit

class MenuViewController: UITableViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var webServer = GCDWebServer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        self.navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let menuCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuCell") as? MenuTableViewCell
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            menuCell?.updateCell(title: "Главная")
        case 1:
            menuCell?.updateCell(title: "Первая игра")
        case 2:
            menuCell?.updateCell(title: "Вторая игра")
        default:
            break
        }
        return menuCell!
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            break
        case 1:                
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowGame", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        case 2:
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowGame", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

**MenuCell code:**

```
import UIKit

class MenuTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var menuTitle: UILabel!

    func updateCell(title: String) {
        menuTitle.text = title
    }
}
```

Comment: **ShowGame** is the identfier of which `segue`?

Comment: @iPeter RootController -> GameViewController

Comment: I implemented just now and it's worked, Can you implement all process what they said github? @MrTishman

Comment: Place a breakpoint and see which case is getting called.

Comment: Can you upload RootController code where you can see all menus?

Comment: @iPeter cases work fine, tested.

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav sure.

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav done.

Comment: Can I upload whole steps @MrTishman

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution [here](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu/issues/255#).

Quick answer:

Storyboard have to looks like "Nav Controller -> [Main View Controller] -> (modal) Side Menu Nav Controller -> (embed/root view controller relationship) Table View Controller (with menu options) -> (push) other view controllers"

[image: example]

Thanks for help @**Abhishek Jadhav** your code works fine!

Answer (score 1):

This Demo will help you to achieve:-

```
class MenuViewController: UITableViewController {

    var menus = ["Menu1", "Menu2", "Menu3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menus.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuCell") as? MenuTableViewCell
        cell.menuTitle?.text = menus[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let firstMenuVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstMenuViewController") as! FirstMenuViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(firstMenuVC, animated: true)
        case 1:
            let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
        case 2:
            let thirdVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewController") as! ThirdViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(thirdVC, animated: true)
        default:
            break
        }
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: If you have done storyboard part correctly what they said in SideMenu Github and try with this code. Because I implemented it's runnable if you want to upload steps from scratch what they show in SideMenu library I upload it?

Comment: No, I have done all correctly, but this code does not work for me too. I tested it on the new project.

Comment: Nothing, same situation like on GIF in the topic.

Comment: May be I didn't make some detail in Storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Try using push instead of segue it looks good

```
let yourVcObject : AnyOutof3Controllers = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AnyIdentifier") as! YourVc
        self.dismiss(animated: false) {
            if let topController = UIApplication.topViewControllerForNav() as? UINavigationController {
                topController.visibleViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(AnyOutof3Controllers)
```

AnyOutof3Controllers means the name of Any controller : for example if you are clicking on 2nd one so instead of this(AnyOutof3Controllers) you have to use the 2ndViewControll

Comment: Thanks, but I found solution. Will post it.